# Upgrading to Wagtail 2.3 and Django 2.1 causes migrations and login to freeze

Tags: django, wagtail

I upgraded our existing site to Wagtail 2.3 from Wagtail 2.1, everything went smoothly and it works fine.

I saw support for Django 2.1 was included, so I upgraded Django - it successfully applied the migrations but froze before script completion. I had to close the terminal window to stop it (cntl-c didn't work).
I also could not login to the site - runserver would freeze up the same way. I tried this with Django 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4 - all with the same results.

I've downgraded to Django 2.0.9 and everything is working fine. I'm not sure if this is a Django bug, a Wagtail bug, or a project bug. There is no output when running `migrate` or `runserver`.

I did look at my Postgres processes - it looked like it was freezing up while trying to read permissions for a user or something related to the content types.

I'm looking for ideas on what else I can check to debug this.

Comment: Do you have something like django debug toolbar installed? If so, you'll want to upgrade that since older versions are slower than glaciers. I've upgraded a lot of websites to Wagtail 2.3 and Django 2.1 and never had any problems. If you have logging turned on, can you share what the errors are (if any)?

Comment: If you do `python manage.py showmigrations` or `SELECT * FROM django_migrations` in the database, does that offer any hints of where your `migrate` command might have frozen?